# How can I “Open an app from an unidentified developer” without using the GUI?

Tags: macos, command-line, gatekeeper

Basically, I used the native `Safari.app` web browser to download a third party application and I want to run / `open` it from the comfort of my `bash` shell / `Terminal.app` CLI; despite the following error message:

```
“<unidentified_thirdparty.app>” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified 
 developer. Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the Mac 
 App Store and identified developers. Safari downloaded this file on <today's_date> 
 from <the.inter.net>.
                                          |[OK]|
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You'll either have to change the settings under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General** > **Allow applications downloaded from:** *to* **Anywhere** *or* in a **Terminal**, strip the `xattr` **com.apple.quarantine** attribute from the downloaded file(s).

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine "unidentified_thirdparty.app"
```

Comment: I was aware of the GUI method. The next part looks spot-on though. What exactly does the `com.apple.quarantine` (attribute) argument refer to?

Comment: @tjt263, Sorry I didn't see your comment until now... All filesystem objects have attributes, e.g. information you'd see in the output of the `ls -l file` command. Filesystem objects also have extended attributes of which `com.apple.quarantine` is one that is assigned to objects downloaded from the Internet by OS X to help prevent arbitrary execution and thus one level of protecting the system. Using `ls -lR@ file` or `xattr −lr file` will show extended attribute information the latter of which will output more extensive information. See `man xattr` for more information.

Comment: Wow. That's interesting. I did not know about that. Do other Operating Systems have something like this in place?

Comment: You can also use either right-click (aka ctrl-click) and choose "Open", to allow executing just that app.

Comment: @HawkenRives, Did you miss in the Title where it said "**without using the GUI?**"!? He wants to use the command line from Terminal, so your comment to my answer is irrelevant!

Comment: Excellent point. I had indeed missed that. (I will note, though, that the first part of your answer requires the use of the GUI, as well.)

Comment: @HawkenRives, Yes it does as it's a global setting not the actual running or opening of the file as the right-click on the file does.  Using `xattr` portion of my answer cover the command line and Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this in the Terminal under a administrator account: `sudo spctl --master-disable`

Comment: This turns off Gatekeeper completely. And it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're dealing with a CLI program that's already in your path but you have trouble figuring out what to pass to `xattr` for `unidentified_thirdparty.app`, you can swap it out for the path to the CLI. In my case, I had `duckdb` in my path, so I executed:

```shell
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine $(which duckdb)
                                       ^^^^^^----adapt to your CLI
```

Answer (score -1):

To do it wisely in command line

1. `xattr -p com.apple.quarantine unidentified_thirdparty.app` outputs something like `0081;5e7fec61;Chrome;6585C1D3-E260-4275-9E6E-505DF8D6B7EE`
2. Copy the output string, replace first 4 characters with `00c1`
3. run `xattr -w com.apple.quarantine 00c1;5e7fec61;Chrome;6585C1D3-E260-4275-9E6E-505DF8D6B7EE unidentified_thirdparty.app`

or, combine these steps into a single command:

```
xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "$(attr -p com.apple.quarantine unidentified_thirdparty.app | sed 's/^.\{4\}/00c1/' )" unidentified_thirdparty.app
```

[My blog post](https://transang.me/macos-open-file-from-unidentified-developers/) on this.

Comment: What does each of the values in the com.apple.quarantine attribute mean?

Comment: @DanielSerodio thanks for the proofreading. The value stores information of the downloader agent (chrome, curl, wget, etc.) and related info. The last id is used to search for the co-located entry in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2` (sqlite format). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219929/1398479) for more info.